# Conservation of momentum collision problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

The problems is as follows:

> A 2000kg Ford was travelling south  when it collided with your 1000kg sports car
>   travelling west. The two badly-damaged cars became entangled in the collision and
>   leave a skid mark that is 20 meters long in a direction 14◦ to the west of the 
>   original direction of travel of the Excursion. The wealthy
>   Excursion driver hires a high-powered lawyer who accuses you of
>   speeding throughthe intersection. Use your knowledge, plus the police
>   officer’s report of the recoil direction, the skid length, and
>   knowledge that the coefficient of sliding friction between the tires
>   and road is $\mu=0.6$, to deduce the original velocities of both cars.
>   Were either of the cars exceeding the 30mph speed limit?

My attempt:
$$\sum \vec p_{initial}=2000v_1(-\hat x)+1000v_2(-\hat y)$$
$$\mu=\frac{F_f}{F_N},F_{N,(after collision)}=3000g,F_f=\mu g(3000)$$
So then using F=ma,
$$\mu g(3000)=(3000)a,a=\mu g$$
$$d=\frac 12 at^2+v_0t$$
In this case, I know that d=20meters, and $a=\mu g$.  However, I do not have a $v_0$.  My thought was to solve this for t, and then ssee what the cars final velocity was.  After the collision, I know that the momentum is:
$$\sum \vec p_{after}=3000v_{after}(-\cos(14^\circ)\hat x-\sin(14^\circ) \hat y)$$
So I get lost on how to combine all of these equations to solve for the initial velocities of the two cars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the kinetic energy = work done by friction to find out the after impact velocity

   $$ \frac{1}{2} (m_{ford} + m_{sports}) v_{after}^2 = \mu (m_{ford} + m_{sports})\, g\, d $$
2. Use conservation of linear momentum to solve for the initial velocities

   $$ \begin{aligned} m_{sports} v_{sports} & =   (m_{ford} + m_{sports}) v_{after} \sin \theta 
        \\  m_{ford} v_{ford} & = (m_{ford} + m_{sports}) v_{after} \cos \theta \end{aligned} $$